# Conditional COUNT in SQL with table Join

Tags: sql, oracle, join, count

I have this query:

```
SQL> SELECT DISTINCT Module.module_name, Instructor.Instructor_name
  2  FROM InstructorMailingAddressModPer
  3  JOIN Module ON InstructorMailingAddressModPer.module_id = Module.module_id
  4  JOIN Instructor ON InstructorMailingAddressModPer.instructor_id = Instructor.instructor_id
  5  ORDER BY module_name;
```

which results in following table:
[image]

I am trying to show only the results with more than one instructors for a module_name like Accounting and Finance for managers, databases, etc

I've come up with following query but messed it up, this query is just to illustrate my thought process:

```
SELECT Module.module_name, Instructor.Instructor_name
  2  FROM (
  3     SELECT Module.module_name, Instructor.Instructor_name
  4     COUNT(DISTINCT InstructorMailingAddressModPer.module_id) CNT
  5     FROM InstructorMailingAddressModPer
  6     JOIN Instructor ON InstructorMailingAddressModPer.instructor_id = Instructor.instructor_id
  7     JOIN Module ON InstructorMailingAddressModPer.module_id = Module.module_id
  8  WHERE CNT > 1;
```

Comment: Share the expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

-- Sample table and data

```
create table modules (module_name varchar2(10), instructor_name varchar2(10));
 insert into modules  values ('A1' , 'Smith');
 insert into modules  values ('A1' , 'Doe');
 insert into modules  values ('A2' , 'Smith');
 insert into modules  values ('A3' , 'Smith');
 insert into modules  values ('A2' , 'Smith');
 insert into modules  values ('A1' , 'Smith');
```

-- you can use either analytical functions or just group by.

```
select * from modules where module_name in (
 select module_name
 from modules
 group by module_name
 having count(distinct instructor_name) >1 );

select distinct module_name, instructor_name , cnt from 
(select module_name, instructor_name , count(distinct instructor_name)over( partition by module_name) cnt
 from modules) 
where cnt > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

One method is window functions:

```
SELECT module_name, Instructor_name, cnt
FROM (SELECT m.module_name, i.Instructor_name,
             COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY m.module_name) as cnt
      FROM InstructorMailingAddressModPer ima JOIN
           Module m
           ON ima.module_id = m.module_id JOIN
           Instructor i
           ON ima.instructor_id = i.instructor_id
     ) mi
WHERE cnt > 1
ORDER BY module_name;
```

Comment: this gives all the values and does not do the partition count. any chance you could have a look at it again? i thought maybe count(*) was the problem and have tried with module_name too but it always gives the whole result in the query above if DISTINCT was not included

Comment: @SamitPaudel looks like you could just add `cnt` to the outer query's `select` list.

Comment: @SamitPaudel . . . That is not in your question, but it is easy to include from the subquery.